# What best practices/principles could help me improve my routine call placement?

Tags: programming-practices, patterns-and-practices, code-organization

I'm trying to change my module's outline since I feel I'm blocking some reuse possibilities, but I don't know how to justify it under the lens of good practices/design principles. Keep in mind this is supposed to become a template for this type of module.

My reasoning for the proposed change lies with the possible reuse of the action subroutines whereas I *could* construct the `chg_rec` action by simply calling `dlt_rec` and `add_rec`. Currently, the reuse of the action routines to compose more complex actions is partially disabled, since I only want one log per action (`CHG_REC`) and because `transaction_recovery` would commit the sub-actions independently.

I do believe the better approach would be to have middleware to handle `auth`, `logs`, and `transaction recovery`, but my architecture isn't there **yet**, so I would appreciate it if the conversation wouldn't deviate into that part of the problem without tackling the question directly.

Right now my module outline looks like this (language RPG ILE):

```
 * Mainline -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C                   exsr      first_routine                                                    
C     action        caseq     'ADD_REC'     add_rec
C     action        caseq     'CHG_REC'     chg_rec
C     action        caseq     'DLT_REC'     dlt_rec
C                   cas                     not_recognized
C                   endcs                                 
C                   exsr      last_routine                                                     
 * ADD_REC -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C     add_rec      begsr                                                                      
C                   exsr      auth
C                   exsr      start_log                                                        
 * add record logic here...                                                                      
C                   exsr      end_log                                                          
C                   exsr      transaction_recovery
C                   endsr                                                                      
 * CHG_REC -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C     chg_rec      begsr                                                                      
C                   exsr      auth
C                   exsr      start_log                                                        
 * chg record logic here...                                                                      
C                   exsr      end_log                                                          
C                   exsr      transaction_recovery
C                   endsr                                                                      
 * DLT_REC -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C     dlt_REC      begsr                                                                      
C                   exsr      auth
C                   exsr      start_log                                                        
 * dlt record logic here...                                                                      
C                   exsr      end_log                                                          
C                   exsr      transaction_recovery
C                   endsr                                                                      
 * NOT_RECOGNIZED -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
C     not_recognizedbegsr                                                                      
C                   exsr      auth
C                   exsr      start_log                                                        
 * send error message                                                                          
C                   exsr      end_log                                                          
C                   exsr      transaction_recovery
C                   endsr                                                                      
 * FIRST_ROUTINE ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C     first_routine begsr                                                                      
 * do some initializations here...                                                             
C                   endsr                                                                      
 * LAST_ROUTINE -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C     last_routine  begsr                                                                      
 * cleanup if needed here...                                                                   
C                   return                                                                     
C                   endsr
```

Right now my proposal is to move the four repeating subroutines (`auth`, `start_log`, `end_log` and `transaction_recovery`) to the `first_routine` and `last_routine` making them look like the following snippet and clearing up all the other routines.

```
 * FIRST_ROUTINE ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C     first_routine begsr                                                                      
 * do some inicializations here...                                                             
C                   exsr      auth
C                   exsr      start_log                                                        
C                   endsr                                                                      
 * LAST_ROUTINE -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C     last_routine  begsr                                                                      
C                   exsr      end_log                                                          
C                   exsr      transaction_recovery
 * cleanup if needed here...                                                                   
C                   return                                                                     
C                   endsr
```

All modules have the `first_routine` and `last_routine`, so that isn't something I'm adding as part of the proposal.

Comment: I'd never thought I'd see RPG on this site. What a nice surprise.

Comment: I don't know what structuring features are available in RPG, but it feels somewhat weird to tear the logging "braces" apart and lump them together with the unrelated authorization and transaction subroutines. Your proposed change would indeed reduce repetition, but at the same time it would impair maintainability. I suppose RPG doesn't provide functional features or annotations which could be used to separate the core functionality of each function from the boilerplate.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner  in what sense would it impair maintainability? Do you mean in regards to reusing the action subroutines to compose more complex actions?


Eventually, I would like to clean up the boilerplate to have a single responsibility per action, but I have some constraints to go that far, as there are more processes that are impacted by a change like that, and I can't act on all of them at once.

Comment: @FernandoSilva at the moment, it looks like `auth` and `start_log` always go together, but suppose an action is added that requires logging but not authorization, the combined `first_routine` isn't applicable anymore. But to really know whether the change is beneficial I know too little about the concrete application.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner, ok, I get where you're going at, but in RPG that `first_routine` could be a bit different when `auth` is not required, we do have modules with that sort of difference, especially when we're talking about inhouse tooling. We follow the outline but leave out some of the boilerplate in those modules specifically.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner, I was reading through the comments again and realized I didn't give you an insight into the application. These modules, that perform actions are all potentially called from external programs, that is why I'm not very concerned with the possibility of removing the `auth` routine or even the `logs` since we want all of that to be tracked in every case. As I mentioned we do have in-house tooling that doesn't perform those actions, however, those are never shipped to production, we just use the same structure for the in-house tools as well.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner, I just found that my approach might be, in concept, similar to what is proposed in regards to refactoring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring), under "Techniques for improving names and location of code" the item "Pull up – in object-oriented programming (OOP), move to a superclass". Although we're not talking about classes here, it would be moving those responsibilities up one level, making the action subroutines more conformant to the Single responsibility principle. I'm going to keep on reading to see if I find anything else

Comment: Separation of Concerns (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) also seems relevant.